# remove quotes from angular $http header

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to communicate with some REST API that works with some kind of token system. The way it is supposed to work is that when I POST to /api/login with a user/pass then I get a token back. Then on subsequent request I should add a X-Auth-Token header with the token and then in the response I will get an updated token. So I figured I could use an interceptor for this, something like below:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider','AppConfig', function($httpProvider,AppConfig) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$injector', function($q, $injector) {
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
        // add token header only if request is not initial token request
        if (!config.url===AppConfig.serverUrl+'/api/login') {
          config.headers['X-Auth-Token'] = $injector.get('$window').localStorage.getItem('token');
          console.log(config);
        }
        return config;
      }
    }
  }]);
}]);
```

When I run the code, I get the token from the API correctly, it gets saved  to the localStorage and then, due to the console.log, I see that on the subsequent request the interceptor adds the X-Token-Auth header to its config.

However, I guess when the actual request is being composed by Angular, it complains about:

```
Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest' : "<token>" is not a valid HTTP header field value.
```

The headers look like this:

```
Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
X-Auth-Token: "Sl6J/xTGXteGwDK/BYt5/FWrrkvSHsz1wFbHlfHNsO7vo1keZad35tHjHansMTwm"
```

The only real difference I see here with when I try something similar in the Chrome postman extension, is that postman sends the token without quotes whereas Angular sends them with quotes around the token.

I guess it would be best if the server would be able to cope with that, but since I don't have control over it, is there a way to remove those quotes?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me what  config.headers['X-Auth-Token']  look like?

Comment: Sure, I added the headers to the post.

Comment: What happens if you try to call `.replace("\"", "")` on `$injector.get('$window').localStorage.getItem('token')` ?

Answer (score -1):

i faced the same problem, so i removed qutotes from start and end:

```
localStorage.getItem('token').replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1')
```